# Continuous functions from a Topology point of view.

Tags: general-topology

How would I show that the product of two continuous functions is continuous if I have a continuous mapping given as $f,g : X \to \mathbb{R}$?

Attempt: I want to find some interval in $\mathbb{R}$, and then show that its preimage $X$ is open. The interval I choose has to contain $f(x)g(x)$ though, which means I need to surround it by some neighborhood.

Comment: Hint: Consider the map $(f,g)$ from $X\times X$ to $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ and then compose this with multiplication.

Comment: Hmm. What do you mean by composing it with multiplication?

Comment: Multiplication is a nice map from $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Still unsure on how to do this one though. I am probably over thinking it.

Comment: Come discuss it in chat then.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline for a proof:

1. Prove that the composition of two continuous functions is continuous. This is a straightforward result that follows from the definitions.
2. Prove that if $f : X \to \Bbb R$, $g : X \to \Bbb R$ are continuous, then $h : X \to \Bbb R^2, h(x) = (f(x), g(x))$ is also continuous.
3. Put $\varphi : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R, \varphi(x, y) = x y$. This is a continuous function. It follows from 1 and 2 that $(\varphi \circ h)(x) = f(x)g(x)$ is also continuous.

To prove 2, consider the set $I_1 \times I_2 \subset \Bbb R^2$ where $I_1, I_2$ are open intervals. We have:

$$
h^{-1}(I_1 \times I_2) = f^{-1}(I_1) \cap g^{-1}(I_2)
$$

But $f^{-1}(I_1), g^{-1}(I_2)$ are both open by the continuity of $f, g$. It follows that the intersection is open. Since every open set in $\Bbb R^2$ is a union of sets of the form $I_1 \times I_2$. The result follows.